# website keeps redirecting into old wordpress url

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, directadmin

i placed a wordpress site in a subfolder in public html and after a while i completely deleted the wordpress subfolder and i want to do something else with server storage but even though now there is no folders in public html in its completely empty when i go to the main domain or root directory it keeps redirecting me to old wordpress directory and there is no subfolder in public html so it gives 404 error and its weird because i have no files in public html.
i did put an index.php in public html and it did not work. site ignored that and got redirected to old wordpress subfolder.
please someone help...

when the wordpress site was up in the subfolder there was another wordpress site in root directory but i did not us it and i deleted that too i dont know if that has anything to do with it

p.s. i deleted everything that belonged to the old wordpress site including databases

Comment: Did you update your database to point to the right place?

Comment: i deleted every thing that belonged to the old wordpress site incloding the databases

Comment: Does your domain DNS point to that subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check you Domain and remove the url for the domain or subdomain. It can't resolve to the file path associated with it and that is what is triggering the 404.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your domain is set to direct to the subfolder.
Did you install wordpress via an software manager at your webhost?
They sometimes set the domain to that application folder automatically.
You should check your domain settings at your host, maybe there is the reason.